# Have $A$ and $A^{-1}$ the same set of eigenvectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Do $A$ and $A^{-1}$ have the same set of eigenvectors?

My try :

Yes they have the same set of eigenvectors. $AX = cX$ we can multiply $A^{-1}$ both sides we get

$$A^{-1} X = c^{-1} X$$

Am I right? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that $A$ is invertible, your argument is correct. If there is an eigenvalue $c=0$, then there would certainly be an issue.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If $\mathbf{v}$ is an eigen vector of $\mathbf{A}$ then $\mathbf{v}$ is also an eigen vector of $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ (provided it exists).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you were a bit too fast. After multiplying both sides of the equality $A\,x = c\,x$ by $A^{-1}$, what you get is $x = c\,A^{-1}x$. Now you must explain that $c\neq0$ (of course, that's because if $c=0$, then $x\in\ker A$ and therefore $A$ would not be invertible). And now, yes, from the equality $x = c\,A^{-1}x$ you can deduce that $A^{-1}x=\frac1cx$ and that, therefore, $x$ is an eigenvector of $A^{-1}$.

Comment: in last line *$A^{-1}$

Comment: Edited. Thanks.